# "Season of Storms" epilogue explained

Tags: the-witcher

This is about the latest book from the "The Witcher" series, *Season of Storms*.

In the epilogue we can read (spoilers!):

> Nimue suddenly felt euphoria, balanced by numbness and the other effects of suffering fear. It’s a dream, she thought. It seems to me a dream. Because this cannot be real.
>
> ‘What’s wrong? Are you okay?’
>
> Nimue plucked up the courage.
>
> ‘This mare…’ in her excitement she had difficulty pronouncing her words. ‘This mare is named Roach. Because that is what you name every horse. Because you, are Geralt of Rivia. The Witcher, Geralt of Rivia.’
>
> He looked at her for a long time. Silent. Nimue also remained silent, staring at the ground.
>
> ‘What is the year now?’
>
> ‘One thousand three hundred and…’ she lifted her surprised eyes. ‘One thousand three hundred and seventy-three after resurrection.‘
>
> ‘If that’s so,’ the white-haired man wiped his face with a gloved hand, ‘then Geralt of Rivia has been long dead. He died a hundred and five years ago.

And later some kind of confirmation:

> ‘But…’ she hesitated. ‘But a hundred years… How is it possible to… How! is it possible?’
>
> ‘Such questions,’ he interrupted her, still with a warm smile, ‘should not be asked by future adepts of Aretuza’.

And finally my question is, can anyone explain the ending?

Did Geralt not only survive but also stop aging? Or somehow the witchers' craft was not ruined and Nimue met a new young witcher? Maybe anyone has insights on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unclear, but its strongly suggested that this is indeed Geralt.

Now lets start from the end of your question: Witchers (just like wizards) age much, much slower: Geralt at some stage during the books says he is over 100, Yennefer if I remember right says in books that she is 94 (and at the beginning of the third "Witcher" game she would be exactly 100), old Vesemir is supposed to be older than the Kaer Morhen (in reality one could guess that he is about 200-300 years old if not more). [Here is an interesting thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/35fefu/how_old_is_geralt_triss_yennefer_vesemir/) about age of main characters in "Witcher" series.

Now, on top of that please note that the "Season of Storms" is not continuation of games but the original book series,

> which ends with Geralt and Yennefer living on their own island in Avalon (Ciri meets sir Galahd there)

that could also alter the speed of passing time in the original world.
Please also note, that Ciri was able to travel in time  - the very same Nimue has seen young Ciri when she was herself a teenager and later on when she was an older, powerful enchantress (this happens in the "Lady of the lake", where Nimue is researching the story of Geralt and Ciri). So it wouldn't be improbable if Ciri somehow moved Geralt in time as well.

Comment: Maybe I underrated the slow-aging ability of witchers, cause it looks like that Geralt was really "young" in epilogue (not a boy, but not a 200-year old). So maybe it really a time travel with the help of Ciri or Ihuarraquax.

Comment: And by the way there is a nice research on http://www.sapkowski.su/modules.php?name=Articles&pa=showarticle&artid=112#13, which says that Geralt was nearly forty at the time he first met with Yennefer and a little more fifty at the end of Saga.

Comment: @GinoPane there are quite confusing information about Geralt's age. Author said that in the beginning of "Baptism of Fire" Geralt is well over 50, in the games (don't remember the part) he says himself that he is close to 100. That would make him about 70 at the end of book series. We don't know how much time passed between end of the books and the game, but king Radovid is described in last book as a "boy", while he is an adult man in the game.

Comment: *"Geralt and Yennefer living on their own island in Avalon (Ciri meets sir Galahd there"* - To be precise, Ciri doesn't really meet Sir Galahad in Avalon, she meets him in Arthurian Britain. In fact it's strongly implied that wherever Geralt and Yennefer are, Ciri is not there.

Comment: Avalon is sort of considered to be heaven, IMO. And you should read this answer https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/131116/125358 for more info on that. In short, if they are alive, it has to have something to do with illusion magic (see the bit about the aguara's final visit to the Witcher), or time travel, or some parallel universe. As ambiguous as he left it, the real meaning could be that all of this was the dream of a dog Ciri had as a child. It is not clear at all.

Answer (score 9):

## It's highly ambiguous, and intentionally so!

Now first of all, it is indeed **strongly implied, even if never clearly stated, that this was Geralt**. Among the obvious characteristics (his visuals, his horse, ...) and the ambiguous dialogue we also have the fact that he was hunting down one of Rissberg's "products", which the story already opened with and which he swore to hunt down.

However, even if that was Geralt, we should **hesitate to draw a clear and definite statement about his survival or his prolonged aging from that**. The entire encounter is highly ambiguous itself. You have to consider the whole surroundings of that encounter. Let's look at the matter:

- There are very mystical and poetic statements about Geralt's place as a legend:

  > She didn't give up. "The Witcher will return from the afterlife! He will return to protect the humans when evil raises its head again. As long as there is dark witchers will be necessary. And the dark is still there after all!"
  >     He was silent for long, looking to the side. Eventually he turned towards her. And smiled.
  >     "The dark is still there", he confirmed. "Despite the achieved progress, which should, as they want us to believe, lighten the dark, eliminate the dangers and drive the fears away. So far the progress hasn't made any major success in this regard. So far the progress only talks us into believing that the dark is only a prejudice which darkens the light, and there's nothing to fear. But that isn't true. Because there will always, always be darkness. And always will the evil spread in the dark, always will there be teeth and claws, murder and blood in the dark. And always will witchers be necessary. And always shall they appear where they're needed. Where they're called. They shall appear when they're called, with sword in hand. With the sword whose brightness drives away the darkness, whose brilliance pierces through the dark. A nice fairy tale, isn't it? And it has a good ending, as every fairy tale should."

Now this could simply be him joking around about it, but it isn't placed in the text for nothing. It generally adds to the motif of a mythical fairy tale ending that the novel series already had afterall. (And like the novel series it presents us with that fairy tale-like ending while *at the same time* self-ironically pointing out, not to say mocking, that fact a little.)

- Then there is the point of her possibly just dreaming it, when she awakes at the side of the street.

  > ...The tale continues, the story never ends. But regarding the *signs*...There is one you don't know. It's called Somne. Look at my palm."
  >     She looked. "Illusion", she could still hear from somewhere. "Everything is illusion."
  >     "Hey girl! Don't sleep, or they'll steal from you!"
  >     She raised her head. Rubbed her eyes. And jumped up from the ground.
  >     "Did I fall asleep? I was asleep?"

However, this is ambiguous, too, since she clearly awakes at the *end* of the forest. So she seems to have crossed the forest *somehow*. It's unclear if it only was Geralt's supposed sign that made her fall asleep and forget him. Yet this itself would still be rather unusual for him to do.

- And last but not least, we also have the [ambiguity of the novel series' ending](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58357/23386) and the unclarity about Geralt's fate.

  > And his possible afterlife in some mystical paradise (supposedly Avalon) in the first place.

All this reinforces that this epilogue isn't really intended to make a clear statement about Geralt's survival or his prolonged aging. Rather than that it **follows the ambiguity, mysticism, and fairy tale-like character of the novel series' ending**. And if anything, it seems to try to establish Geralt's fate as somewhat of **a legend, a mythical hero, a ghost striving through the wilderness and protecting humans from monsters**. But if he really *is* an actual ghost, or just a legend whispered and never seen by anyone, or the real Geralt returning into the world and living beyond his age, or if Nimue just dreamed all this, is a moot point. We just can't say and we're not really supposed to clearly say. **You can and should decide that for yourself.**

---

<sub>(In lack of an official English translation, let alone one I have at hand, the exceprts in this answer have been translated into English by me from Erik Simon's official German translation of *Season of Storms*.)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Nimue hears at the end the voice of the vixen telling Geralt it's just an illusion, in parallel to her saying its just a dream; and just before this epilogue started the vixen was telling Geralt how powerful her kind used to be, that their powers weren't just confined to simple illusions and as he touched Yennefer (the illusion) he was able to get a glimpse of a time in the future where a little girl (Nimue) not only remembered him but his horse and was in love/obsessed with his **legend**. Now this also served to give Geralt consolation for spending the past few chapters saying over and over how much bad luck he's had and that nothing he does ends well. That all his efforts are futile and not appreciated, and Dandelion keeps trying to assure him, but the last time he said it Dandelion didn't answer.

And then the vixen appeared. And it also serves us not only knowing that Geralt was soothed knowing it's not all for naught - that his journey has a purpose; and also, in my opinion, Nimue represents **us the readers**, her "dream" was to say that one way or the other our hero survived; whether its through Nimue's memories/another dimension/whatever - it doesn't matter. What matters is that our hero is immortal. That dying to a peasants pitchfork has no meaning. The journey is whats truly important.

Comment: That's a very nice answer, though it'd be cool if you capitalised proper names the next time ;)

Answer (score 3):

Serously, I don't think the Epiloge is to be taken literally and has nothing to do with Geralts story. It is clear, the person Nimue talks to is indeed Geralt, but I got the feeling the conversation is more of a placeholder for a conversation between the author (Geralt) and the reader (Nimue) sharing their feelings at the end of their travels. This feeling is strengthened through the fact that it is unclear if the  encounter was real or just a dream. On Geralt's statment that the witcher died one hundred and five years ago Nimue replies that this can't really be the end, that there has to be more, about Yennefer, about Ciri, and in this asking the question most readers had eventually. Geralt just answers that it is time to part with him, but admits that a story never ends.

This suggests that Andrzej Sapkowski isn't planning to write annother story about Geralt but leaves the option open to return to the witcher universe as there will be always darkness and the need for a witcher. I don't have any facts to support my theory, but I wouldn't be surprised if Season of Storms was Andrzej's farewell to the wichter's story. That could mean he's not planning to write another story in the witcher universe right now, but in the future it will be a possibility. As he is not very fond of others completing his story, he's probaply not talking about the witcher games.

So my final conclusion is, that the ending is unrelevant for the story but just a message of Andrzej to his readers and giving Geralt a final goodbye that his fairy tale and legend deserves. In the end the only clear thing he tells is that a story never really ends, leaving us hanging in the balance between the sadness about a lost companion and the hope for another chance to dive into Geralt's world.

Just be aware of the fact that literature doens't always mean what is written, and sometimes the true message has to be found between the lines.

Comment: This answer needs some grammar and spelling check. Also, while speculative answers are answers as well, we encourage answers that can be backed by canon information. Just for future reference.

Comment: i'm sorry for the grammar, english isn't my native language. For the Rest, everything is a speculative answer in this case. There is just the possibility that the ending cannot the explained through a cannon approach.

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting and grammar a little. I think this is a very well-reasoned answer and an excellent take on the matter. You don't necessarily need canon information (especially since there clearly is *none* here at all, which holds for a majority of witcher questions) if you can present your approach in such a well-reasoned way and by proper argumentation against the work itself.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach  -  which is exactly why I added "Just for future reference"

Answer (score 0):

I just finished reading Season of Storms and have been trying to understand the ending. The two answers I found here were really helpful and I would like to thank for them.

In addition I noticed something about the ending that is usually not mentioned. After Nimue wakes up at the ending there is the line: She looked. "Illusion", she could still hear from somewhere. "All an illusion." Now I saw this exact phrase, "Illusion, all an illusion." in the previous chapter in which Geralt and Dandelion runs into the vulpess (the fox devil). After the vulpess transforms to Yennefer and Geralt touches her cheek there is the line: "Illusion," He heard the vixen say. "All an illusion."

In my opinion the epilogue that took place in Jay Forest wasn't a dream. It was an illusion performed by the vulpess. She created an illusion or took form of Geralt for Nimue, just like she transformed into Yennefer for Geralt. I haven't thought deeply about what kind of a message Sapkowski is trying to convey here but I think an illusion performed by the vulpess could be an alternative to the dream hypothesis.

PS: Sorry for the writing style if what I am trying to say is unclear, it's my first time writing something like this on a website.

Answer (score 0):

I also see the ending as an illusion created by a vixen. But not the vixen we met in the story, but rather her daughter who Geralt saved on the ship by doing what was good. And now the daughter has become a full fledged vixen herself and is also doing what is good by protecting and saving the innocent the way Geralt saved and protected her. And she has continued carrying out Geralt’s mission of eradicating the monsters created by the wizards of Rissberg when she happened to save Nimue while disguised under the illusion of Geralt.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this theory that you could [edit] in?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I think Nimue and the other one Nimue had come to her in Lady of the Lake aren't able to interact with their dreams. They can only observe. Nimue was able to interact with Geralt at that moment.

Geralt at the end of Lady of the Lake was in bandages and feeling pain. Dead people don't feel physical pain. Maybe Ciri cried simply because she had to leave them (why I don't know). That alone could be the bad ending Ciri was referring to.

For all we know Geralt could have come back a long time ago. He could have been on Avalon for a few short months maybe. With a 100 years of untold story from then until when Nimue meets him in the forest.

The open ending was done deliberately and we will never know what the truth is.

Comment: But how can we be sure it's really Geralt, even if Nimue believes it is?

Comment: I think you are mixing up Nimue with Condwiramurs. The latter was a dreamer, not Nimue... and that ability has nothing to do with the ending of Season of Storms.

Answer (score 0):

I just created this account to post an idea that I have not read here yet.

First, I like the previous comments a lot that suggest that the white-haired witcher (/Geralt) and Nimue in the epilogue could represent Sapkowski and the readers. It certainly seems that there are many parallels; Nimue's questions are often the ones asked by fans, and the responses provided are the ones Sapkowski tends to give (or intentionally does not want to give). But beyond the message Sapkowski wants to deliver to the readership as Sapkowski, I am sure that this epiloque also has a meaning relevant to the story.
Second, the idea that the witcher here could be an illusion-Geralt created by the daughter of the vixen. It seems a very reasonable explanation that makes a lot of sense.

I want to introduce **another idea** that I found attractive if not assuming an illusion (which is of course always a kind of easy explanation). This is speculative, of course, but I try to support it with the limited material we got:
The white-haired man never confirms his identity, he even talks about Geralt as someone he knew well and had a friendly relationship with (e.g., him saying Geralt would probably be happy if he knew people would still remember him and even the name of his horse). It is fair enough to take for granted that the white-haired man is a witcher (two swords, fighting a monster, collecting a sample, knowing Geralt well and seemingly personally from long ago). White hair itself is not something very unnatural or rare, it is just that we do not know other witchers than Geralt with white hair because witchers age slower and they usually die sooner or later in combat before they grow old (not in terms of years, but biologically). This was once stated by one of the witchers in Kaer Morhen in one of the canon books, so we can consider this as true. In addition, it is canon that there are only a few witchers left and "reproduction" is to be expected very unlikely.

At the time of the book series, among the few witchers, Vesemir is certainly among the oldest if not the oldest. If he did not die for another 105 years after what that white-haired man referred to as Geralt's death in the epilogue, then Vesemir could probably have naturally **white hair** by now. Even if we want to believe that naturally grown white hair was not as bright white as Geralt's famous hair, we must consider that Nimue in the epilogue has never seen the real Geralt. She just knows the stories and now sees a white-haired man with two swords killing a monster (and it was dark..). So, it could easily be an even older Vesemir with naturally white hair. Also keep in mind that Nimue was obsessed with the stories about Geralt, Ciri, and Yennefer. So, it is very likely she would believe to see Geralt whenever she meets any man with white or grey hair, two swords, with a horse..

The **way how this white-haired man talked to Nimue** reminded me more of how conversations between Vesemir and the other witchers were betrayed in the other books (i.e., more like a warm-hearted father figure, lecturing at times, but not as harsh or blunt as Geralt or the other younger witchers sometimes have been with Ciri).

Also, the **actions of a (potential) Vesemir** make a lot of sense to me: He may know about Geralt's story in the Season of Storms and may want to finish Geralt's uncompleted tasks. Also, Ciri may have told him about everything that happened in the canon books, including Nimue and how she helped her in a different time line. So, this means that Vesemir has a special interest to guide her on her path to fulfill her destiny (which is to help his own dear friends-of-the-past in the future) when he realized who she was. And this is exactly what the white-haired man did and told Nimue (i.e., he helps her literally to get out of that forest, he guides her onto her future path, and he tells her that she has a specific path to go that is different than his). He is reluctant, rightfully so, to tell her the plain truth about Geralt's story and about his identity because he sees that her believe in the stories is the prime motivation to pursue her path and to become what is required to fulfill the important role she will have in the future.

The **Vesemir theory is supported by intro** before chapter 1 and this is also the reason why I got this idea in the first place: There is this small intro before chapter 1 where a quote was cited about the dark in the world, that there will always be evil hiding in the dark. This was quoted from Vesemir in fact, and it is extremely similar to the words of the white-haired man to Nimue. Now, one could argue the same for the quote of the vixen (i.e., "illusion.. all is illusion"). However, I first find it way more suspicious that the comparably long quote from Vesemir is almost identical than the very short one of the vixen. Second, Vesemir has a good reason to say that to Nimue, too, because he does not want to take that illusion from her and, thus, he fuels her curiosity that eventually will make her fulfill her destiny. Third, we can even imagine that Vesemir knows about the encounter between Geralt and the vixen as it was a rather extraordinary story in Geralt's life (otherwise why would Sapkowski tell us this one) and they met a second time in the book's last chapter before the epilogue (maybe even more times later). Anyway, I found it reasonable that Vesemir knows about the story and perhaps even this quote. Maybe he likes it and that just made him use it, but more importantly, as pointed out, he had good reason to say that anyways.

**Critique**: Some may ask why Vesemir, if it was him, asked Nimue for the year, and some may think that this question is proof that the white-haired must be a time-traveler or such kind. I do not think so, and I could imagine that Vesemir was not asking this because of having no idea whether the present is before or after Geralt's death but how many years exactly already passed. This would make sense because the conversation continues with him expressing his surprise that people still remember him nowadays. So, my explanation is that Vesemir at this time has lived a really long life and perhaps he was traveling a lot alone during the last 100 years when Geralt and perhaps also the other wolf witchers died (one died during one of the battles in book canon, so there are only how many remaining? 2?). So, it is easy to imagine that he has a different sense of time, years, and memory compared with regular humans. So, assume he is Vesemir, traveling alone, honoring Geralt's life by completing some of his tasks, living the witcher life as the last one of his school perhaps, he is probably not too much interested in politics and what is going on in the regular human's world except for the good and the bad and to protect humans in general (no matter the time) and he may have disconnected a bit with what is going on. So, a rather young girl is now talking to him about Geralt, Vesemir may be surprised in the first moment because in regular human terms (which is not Vesemir's perspective) she is too young to have experienced that or heard as a story by her parents or even grandparents. So that means the stories have become more of the caliber of legends. And that is something not so obvious for him as for us when a young looking one talks about it 100 years later because he has a different sense of time, so he needs to reevaluate. So, in my opinion, this question could be less of an indication of someone time traveling and more like "wait a moment, what year is it exactly? hm.. that means it's already 105 years since then, that means a crazy long time for these regular humans".

What do you think and do you have other critiques on this theory?

Answer (score -1):

I don't really think that it was Vixen in the end. Why would she go and meet Nimue? Nimue is no one to her and has no reason to do that more than 100 years after she met Geralt. To me it might be Geralt. The end of the saga strongly implies that Geralt and Yennefer ended up in the world of unicorns. Many people think that they are dead in some kind of "heaven", but it's the unicorn world in my opinion. Why would Geralt have bandages on his wounds and feel pain etc?

Also they came there by a boat, the same way Ciri escaped the world some time before. Also the Elven king suggested to Ciri that time in their world passes much slower than in Geralt's world. So it is very possible that Geralt and Yennefer have spent some time in the unicorn world, maybe years and then they somehow managed to get back, but as in the unicorn world only years passed, in Geralt's it might be maybe 100 years. That might be reason why he seem to be the same age.

Also, how would Vixen know about IDRs and plate with number etc. If it would be really Vixen for some reason, she would probably create different illusion. But that's only my opinion. I understand that some might think it was Vixen because in the end Geralt says it is only an illusion, but that might be just because Geralt doesn't want her to know he is alive, he just want to stay dead for everyone and make her believe it was just a dream or illusion, so he can leave in peace retired.

And also I think the epilogue is relevant to Geralt's story, as this scene was also mentioned in book from saga. (Nimue saved by white haired Witcher). It is basically part of lore and it obviously happened.

But I also believe that this meeting of Geralt and Nimue is a metaphor where the author is Geralt and the reader is Nimue, but it doesn't mean it hasn't happened.